# duplicate link display error

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've asked a question earlier this day that might be a duplicate and I got this message box:

[image]

I tried to refresh the page a couple of times but the error with the link display was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, this will be fixed next build (which shouldn't be long)

Comment: Well, the best fix would be that we don't ask duplicate question... :)

Comment: For some reason, someone downvoted this o.O +1

Comment: @Cerbrus maybe they like seeing raw html and would rather we didn't fix it; it takes all sorts to make a world...